# Navbar Bootstrap Framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been playing around with Bootstrap Framework, and have faced a weird problem.

http://multisupport.dk/

- As you can see, my menu is acting really strange, and I want it to stay inside the container, that wraps around the entire page.

I have tried serveral methods, but none of them work, changing max-width to 1200px; and centering the nav bar didn't do the trick.

And after serveral hours of trying to play around with the elements, I have came to the solution I must search for help else where.

I hope someone can give me a solution, to make the menu, not extend more than the container that is wrapped around it :)

Comment: you dont need a container class inside the nav element, if you plan to add a container class, add a row class after to offset the padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem with the same function, replace the following lines

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top affix-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
```

with these lines

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top affix-top">
    <div class="container">
```

Comment: I decided to delete my answer since, as you noted, the navbar will be hidden if you just remove `navbar-fixed-top`